# Passing Objects between View Controllers in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, oop

I have 3 Classes Class A, Class B, Class C.

I am Passing Variable from ClassB to ClassA and then popping ClassB(View Controller)

//ClassB.m

```
    ClassA *obj = [[ClassA alloc]init];
    [obj passValue:value];
    [obj release];

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //It will pop and show ClassC View Controller.
```

//ClassA.h

```
NSString* storeValue;
-(void)passValue:(NSString*)getValue;
```

//ClassA.m

```
-(void)passValue:(NSString*)getValue
{
   NSLog(@"Value is %@",getValue); // I am Getting Value Here
   storeValue = getValue; 
}
```

In ClassC. I am Pushing ClassA View Controller

ClassC.m

```
ClassA *objA = [[ClassA alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objA animated:YES];
[objA release];
```

Now in Class A. Inside View Didload. I tried to print storeValue. but it returns null. What i am doing wrong here. can anyone guide me do it in right way with Sample Code.

I tried using property to access the variable. but it returns null value.

Thanks,
Anish

Comment: Create Property of storeValue in Class A and make it nonatomic and retain then synthesize it and then try it. and use it as self.storevalue

Comment: See this helpful blog post: http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/passing-data-between-view-controllers/

Comment: after popViewControllerAnimated only viewWillAppear will called not viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 2):

I had considered following hierarchy of class -
  C -> A -> B
You don't need to create any object for Class A, as that is already on navigation stack. Use -

```
NSMutableArray *activeControllerArray = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
for(int i = 0, i <[activeControllerArray  count], i++) {
    if([[activeControllerArray objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[ClassA class]) {
        //Set Property and instance variable here
        ClassA *obj = [activeControllerArray objectAtIndex:i];
        obj.someVariable = somevalue; //you can use in any way that you want

        break;
     }
}
//Pop to previous view now
```

Comment: @rishi +1 you're right, you're accessing to the right pointer.

Comment: i didn't pushed the view controller yet.. i passed the value into the ClassA view controller. after popping the view controller only, i am pushing a Class A view Controller..

Comment: so hierarchy is like -> Class C -> B - > C -> A, and when we want to set property at that time Class object not on navigation stack.

Comment: Class C -> ClassB --> ClassC --> Class A. i am passing value from class B to Class A. and Popping Class B. so Class C will be Visible and now i am Pushing Class A and try access the value that i passed earlier in view didload

Comment: then in that case you need to create property of Class C as well, first pass property from Class B to Class C using same navigation stack way to way you want, and then pass that property to Class A at the time of push only.

Comment: i am not clear abou this. can u explain me little briefly with sample code(if possible). :-)

Comment: You have already created property for Class A, now create similar property for Class C, when you are popping from Class B to Class C then set the property using the same way above described, then when you are creating instance of Class A in CLassC for pushing, then before push statement set the property of Class A with this value. Is it clear enough?

Comment: can we have a chat for few minutes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11047/discussion-between-rishi-and-anish)

Answer (score 1):

You are actually refering to multiple instances of ClassA. In ClassB you create a new ClassA's object and set a value.

In classC you are creating a differnt Instance of ClassA and then checking the value set for previous instance.

You can access the value set in 'storeValue' in all instances if its declared static.

Else Instance variables belongs to instance of class and is managed seperatley by each instance.

---

I Think you are doing it entirely wrong this time.

1. You could implement delegate methods to pass the object back before
   poping and then use it.
2. If you use static variable, it will be common for all instance of
   that Class. Which may not be desirable.
3. Or you could post an NSNotification. And pass the object along with it.
   Listeners of those notifications could catch it and handle it
   differently.

Answer (score 0):

Change your class as you are popping to class C:

```
ClassC *obj = [[ClassC alloc]init];
[obj passValue:value];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
[obj release];
```

Comment: then check that is there any value befor you pass it. by placing break point

Comment: no i am not passing any value before it. i can access the variable inside the function when i pass. but i want to access the variable when view controller loads.

Answer (score 0):

As @JS Rodrigues said, you're not pointing to exists instance of ClassA, you're just creating another instance of ClassA.

To get the existing instance of ClassA you can control on the stack of the navigationcontroller (this code is similar to @rishi code but use fast enumetarion):

```
for (UIViewController *obj in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[ClassA class]]) {
        ClassA *ca=(ClassA *)obj;
        [ca passValue:value];
    }
}
```

Comment: i didn't pushed the view controller yet.. i passed the value into ClassA view controller. after popping the view controller only, i am pushing a Class A view Controller..

Comment: Then, set a property `ClassA` in `ClassC`, get a reference of this from `ClassB` and then push.

Answer (score 0):

don't print the value in viewDidLoad

viewDidLoad fire before after allocation and before you passes the variable, because of that, your variable returns NULL

if you really do need to pass this way, set the variable in the header , then use the passing method

for instance :

you want to pass string myString from A to B, and then go to B and print the string

on A, import the B and then do the following function

```
self.bViewController = [[BVIEWCONTROLLER alloc]init];

[self.bViewController setmyString:myString];

//if u're running OS lower than 5.0, include this
[self.bViewController viewDidAppear];
```

after that you print the myString variable in the b view controller, INSIDE the viewDidAppear method.

good luck

Comment: well in my case, in my app, in 4.3 the viewDidAppear didn't fire as it should, because im pushing my viewController with a different way :3